C++ : if iterator is an object, why can't it be initialized to a reference iterator?
Supposedly we have the below:
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  vector <int> v {1,2,3};
  vector <int>::iterator v_i1 = v.begin();
  vector <int>::iterator &v_i2 = v.begin(); // error out - initial value of reference to non-const must be an lvalue
}

Understanding:

v.begin() will return an iterator - which is actually an object
v_i1 a variable is initialized with the iterator return from begin(). No issue
If v.begin() returns an iterator (object here??), why can't it be assigned to reference v_i2? Is it because v.begin() return a rvalue?

Thanks for helping me to understand better.

v.begin() returns prvalue, so you should use vector <int>::iterator&&.

Same, to_string() returns an string object which is prvalue.

Who told you that objects cannot be rvalues?

Non const reference can't bind to rvalue returnrd by std::vector::begin(). Make the reference to const.
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  vector <int> v {1,2,3};
  vector <int>::iterator v_i1 = v.begin();
  const vector <int>::iterator &v_i2 = v.begin();
}

Or, as commented, make it rvalue reference. The both prolong the temporary object' lifetime to the scope of the reference.
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  vector <int> v {1,2,3};
  vector <int>::iterator v_i1 = v.begin();
  const vector <int>::iterator &v_i2 = v.begin();
  vector <int>::iterator &&v_i3 = v.begin();
}


I don't understand why begin() return a rvalue and not lvalue. That's the part i couldn't comprehend. Clearly it says iterator is an object (lvalue). So why begin() returns rvalue?

See prvalue: a function call ..., whose return type is non-reference. std::vector<T,Allocator>::begin returns non-reference iterator. It returns prvalue (pure rvalue) because iterator is constructed at call, it's a temporary object.

says iterator is an object more correct would be returned iterator is a temporary object.

@yapkm01 object and lvalue are totally different concepts and look like you confused the two. An integer variable can be lvalue. A temporary object is a prvalue.
